Permissions for shared partition in Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot
I use a ThinkPad E14 Gen 4, and have the following configuration for my drives. I dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with Windows 11 Pro.



Disk
Parition
Type
OS




0
Windows OS (BitLocker encrypted)
NTFS
Windows


0
Windows Data (BitLocker encrypted)
NTFS
Windows


0
Windows Applications (BitLocker encrypted)
NTFS
Windows


0
SHARED
NTFS
Windows and Ubuntu


0
Dev (BitLocker encrypted)
ReFS
Windows


1
root
ext4
Ubuntu


1
/home
ext4
Ubuntu


1
swap
swap
Ubuntu



I want the "SHARED" parition to be accessible by both the OS. I crated it as an NTFS parition from Windows and then mounted it in Ubuntu using the GUI. I then copied some files into it from Ubuntu. So far both Windows and Ubuntu can read them, but Windows cannot modify/add/delete.
What should I do such that both OSes can modify/add/delete files only in the SHARED partition? I am an admin on Windows and am a sudoer on Ubuntu.

Response to common solutions presented here

Fast start-up is off. I've had normal dual-boot (without sharing files) for about a year and it works perfectly.
Many of the related questions asked earlier were about file visibility. That's not my issue, both OSes can read the files, but I want both to be able to write as well.
Most people seem to have problems with Linux not being able to modify/read the files. In my case, Windows cannot modify.
The partition in question is not encrypted. I checked that, and I can read its files anyways.

Output of lsblk -o +FSTYPE
$ lsblk -o +FSTYPE
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS                            FSTYPE
loop0         7:0    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2318                      squashfs
loop1         7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5                           squashfs
loop2         7:2    0    64M  1 loop /snap/core20/2379                      squashfs
loop3         7:3    0  74.3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1612                      squashfs
loop4         7:4    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1621                      squashfs
loop5         7:5    0 271.4M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4955                     squashfs
loop6         7:6    0   272M  1 loop /snap/firefox/5091                     squashfs
loop7         7:7    0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127             squashfs
loop8         7:8    0  11.1M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/147             squashfs
loop9         7:9    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143              
loop10        7:10   0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176                
loop11        7:11   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535           
loop12        7:12   0  10.5M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1173                  
loop13        7:13   0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465                      
loop14        7:14   0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1218                  
loop15        7:15   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759                      
loop16        7:16   0   568K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/253    
loop17        7:17   0   564K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/247    
loop18        7:18   0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/526                  squashfs
loop19        7:19   0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/532                  
nvme1n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk                                        
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0  93.1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell ext4
│                                     /                                      
├─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi                              vfat
├─nvme1n1p3 259:3    0  93.1G  0 part /home                                  ext4
└─nvme1n1p4 259:4    0  51.2G  0 part [SWAP]                                 swap
nvme0n1     259:5    0 953.9G  0 disk                                        
├─nvme0n1p1 259:6    0   100M  0 part                                        vfat
├─nvme0n1p2 259:7    0    16M  0 part                                        
├─nvme0n1p3 259:8    0 292.2G  0 part                                        BitLocker
├─nvme0n1p4 259:9    0   715M  0 part                                        ntfs
├─nvme0n1p5 259:10   0 193.4G  0 part                                        BitLocker
├─nvme0n1p6 259:11   0  50.8G  0 part                                        BitLocker
├─nvme0n1p7 259:12   0 385.5G  0 part                                        BitLocker
├─nvme0n1p8 259:13   0  29.3G  0 part /mnt/win-shared                        ntfs
└─nvme0n1p9 259:14   0     2G  0 part                                        ntfs

nvme0n1p8 is the SHARED partition.
ls -al of files and folders
eo is a stand-in for my username.
Root of the mount
/mnt/win-shared$ ll
total 53
drwxrwxrwx 1 eo    root  4096 Oct 17 13:05  ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Oct 12 10:56  ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 eo    root     0 Oct 12 12:10 '$RECYCLE.BIN'/
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo    eo    4096 May  7 17:03  books/
-rwx------ 1 eo    root   112 Oct 12 12:09  bootTel.dat*
drwxr-xr-x 1 eo    root  4096 Oct 16 20:49  component-documentation/
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo    eo    4096 Oct  8 13:16  edu/
drwxr-xr-x 1 eo    root  4096 Oct 12 12:19  events/
d--------- 1 eo    root  4096 Oct 12 12:09  found.000/
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo    eo    4096 Apr  5  2024  important/
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo    eo    4096 Sep 24 22:37  docs/
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo    eo    4096 Sep  4 00:21  research/
drwx------ 1 root  root  8192 Oct 17 12:37 'System Volume Information'/
drwxr-xr-x 1 eo    root     0 Oct 12 12:00  test/
drwx------ 1 eo    eo       0 Oct 13 18:31  .Trash-1000/
drwxr-xr-x 1 eo    root  4096 Oct 16 18:20 'College Notes'/

Inside specific folder
/mnt/win-shared/edu/notes$ ll
total 76
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo eo  4096 Oct 13 20:05 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo eo  4096 Oct  8 13:16 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eo eo 48378 Oct 13 20:05 aws.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eo eo  1182 Mar 17  2024 chemistry.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eo eo  4794 Sep 21 23:53 mpmc.md
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo eo     0 Oct 13 18:31 pdfs/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eo eo  1683 Feb 10  2024 power-electronics.md
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo eo  4096 Oct 11 20:09 friend-meas-da2/
drwxrwxr-x 1 eo eo     0 Sep 21 23:16 .vscode/

Error on attempting to edit a file
I opened aws.md with Notepad and tried to edit it. It gives the following error when trying to save.

Permissions in Windows

Response of findmnt
$ findmnt /mnt/win-shared 
TARGET   SOURCE  FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/win-shared
         /dev/nvme1n1p8
                 fusebl rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,all


From Linux, what's the problematic files' mode (as in chmod) and ACL (if that's even a thing on NTFS and Linux)?

@DanielB The problem seems to be across the partition. I cannot edit anything. I've edited post with one output for the root of the mount and one for a specific folder (files in which definitely aren't editable by Windows, I tried).

What does Windows do when you try to modify something? Does it hang, or does it show an "Access denied" error, or does it show a "Read-only disk" error, or what?

@grawity_u1686 it is a form of access denied, I think. I've edited with a screenshot

eccentricOrange: In your table, is exFAT supposed to be ext4? Why not use exFAT for the shared volume instead of NTFS?

Okay, looks like the permissions are okay as far as Linux can see. Please check the resulting ACLs from Windows: What are the ACL entries, what is the file/folder owners?

@DavidAnderson yeah, it's supposed to be ext4, my bad. I tried exFAT for SHARED but since it didn't have permissions that just confused both OSes.

@DanielB edited with screenshot of Windows ACL for the aws.md file. My Windows user is not even listed there. I feel like we've narrowed the problem down, but I'm not sure if I should mess around with settings here.

What’s the output of findmnt /mnt/win-shared on Linux? What’s your umask? I just did a little test with both ntfs-3g and the native NTFS driver and everything I created shows up on Windows with an “Everyone” ACL entry permitting everything.

@DanielB sorry I took so long to revert. I've added the output
